# Side length of the squares

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, pythagorean-triples

Consider the following figure where $ORQP$ and $RSTQ$ are squares of same side length. $O,R,T$ lies on the circle with centre $B$.The radius of the circle is $5$ units. Find the side length of the squares.
[image]

My try:

Let the side of the squares be $a$.

Let $W$ be the mid point of $RT$. Then we know that $BW$ is $\perp$ to $RT$. Also $PR$ is $\perp$ to $RT$. Now i assumed that $RW \parallel PB$.

So we have $WB=PR=a\sqrt{2}$

By Pythagoras theorem in $\Delta BRW$ we get
$$25=(a\sqrt{2})^2+\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$$

Which gives $a^2=10$ and hence $a=\sqrt{10}$.

But geometrically how to prove that $RW \parallel PB$?

Comment: If you convince yourself that the given squares are two-ninths of a larger three-by-three square, you'll see various relations that have to hold, including the desired parallelism.

Comment: You can set up coordinates to show that $RW \parallel PB$. $\quad$ There's a nice proof of this question where you tile the circle with $ 3\times 3 $ squares, and the circle passes through 8 points on the perimeter.

Comment: Calvin Lin could you please show the demonstration?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Take quadrant formed by $\angle ABU$.

Firstly, $QR = QT$ and $\angle RQT = 90^0$ so it must be on the perpendicular bisector of $RT$, which is $BW$.

That gives us $\angle TQW = \angle BQP = \angle BPQ = 45^0$. We also have $\angle RPQ = 45^0$.

So $\angle RPB = 90^0$ and $PR \parallel BW$.

Also see the $9$ squares that Calvin Lin referred to in comments.

That leads to side of the square $s$ given by,

$(3s)^2 + s^2 = d^2 \implies s = \frac{d}{\sqrt{10}}$

where $d$ is the diameter of the circle.

Comment: Note: Being nitpick, the 9-square configuration needs a further justification. One way of doing this is to realize that we can rotate the figure about $B$ by $90^circ$ clockwise, which brings O to T (because $ \angle OBT = 90^\circ$).

Comment: @CalvinLin that's correct. I showed a proof based on OP's diagram (solid lines in my diagram). I left $9$-square configuration just as an addition.